# Redefinition of a static data member

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to setup NETA framework on Omnetpp 4.3 and INET 2.1, I get the an error says:

```
'NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-
     Wattributes]"
```

even there are no dll import or export in the project

the line that gives the error is in file called NA_UDPBasicBurst.cc

```
#include "NA_UDPBasicBurst.h"

#include "UDPControlInfo_m.h"
#include "IPvXAddressResolver.h"

using std::cout;


Define_Module(NA_UDPBasicBurst);

simsignal_t NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal = SIMSIGNAL_NULL;
```

and its defined in the .h file like this :

```
#ifndef NA__INET_UDPBASICBURST_H
#define NA__INET_UDPBASICBURST_H

#include <UDPBasicBurst.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "common/log/NA_NesgLog.h"



class INET_API NA_UDPBasicBurst : public UDPBasicBurst {

  protected:
    int numHopsTotal;
    double avHopCount;
    static simsignal_t hopCountSignal;
```

can anyone help me with that please.

I am trying to setup NETA framework on Omnetpp 4.3 and INET 2.1

Comment: *"even there are no dll import or export in the project"* what do you think `INET_API` and other macros do?

Comment: so what do you suggest 
where should i look

Comment: Add INET_API to the definition of NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal in the .cc file.

Comment: i tried this INET_API  simsignal_t NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal = SIMSIGNAL_NULL;
it says:
Multiple markers at this line
 - 'NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-
  Wattributes]

 - declaration of 'simsignal_t NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal' outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]

 - definition of 'simsignal_t NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal' is marked 'dllimport'

Comment: According to https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/common/INETDefs.h the preprocessor symbol `INET_EXPORT` needs to be defined if you're compiling your shared lib and `INET_IMPORT` in the target(s) linking the shared lib. If you aren't using a shared library, neither `INET_IMPORT` nor `INET_EXPORT` must be defined for the target(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding __declspec(dllexport) like this :

```
simsignal_t __declspec(dllexport) NA_UDPBasicBurst::hopCountSignal = SIMSIGNAL_NULL;
```